# How do I make the page created from my module visible only to anonymous users?

Tags: 7, routes

I programatically created a page using the following code.

```
/**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
 function page_prog_menu() {
   $items['page_prog/custom'] = array(
     'title' => 'My Custom page',
     'page callback' => 'page_prog_custom',
     'access arguments' => array('access content'),
   );
   return $items;
 }

 /**
 * Custom callback function.
 */ 
 function page_prog_custom() {
   $content['raw_markup'] = array(
     '#type' => 'markup',
     '#markup' => '<p>Hello world</p>',
   );

 return $content;
 }
```

I need to make this page visible only to anonymous users. How can I achieve this?

I have tried with `hook_permission()`, but it doesn't help.

```
/**
* Implements hook_permission().
*/
function page_prog_permission() {
  return array(
    'access page_prog content' => array(
    'title' => t('Access content for the pages created programatically'),
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
/**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
 function page_prog_menu() {
   $items['page_prog/custom'] = array(
     'title' => 'My Custom page',
     'page callback' => 'page_prog_custom',
     'access callback' => 'user_has_custom_role',
     'access arguments' => array('access content'),
   );
   return $items;
 }

 /**
 * Custom callback function.
 */ 
 function page_prog_custom() {
   $content['raw_markup'] = array(
     '#type' => 'markup',
     '#markup' => 'Hello world',
   );

 return $content;
 }

 function user_has_custom_role($roles) {
    if (user_is_anonymous()) {
       return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: `user_has_custom_role()` doesn't get any `$roles` parameter, but the values passed in the access arguments array, but in this case setting the access arguments doesn't have sense, since the access callback is not going to use them. Furthermore, `user_has_custom_role()` is more complex than required: It is sufficient to use `return user_is_anonymous()` as function body.

Answer (score 0):

'access arguments' => array('access page_prog content'),

Answer (score 0):

Change the access callback to [`user_is_anonymous()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_is_anonymous/7.x), and the page will be visible just to anonymous users.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function page_prog_menu() {
  $items['page_prog/custom'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Custom page',
    'page callback' => 'page_prog_custom',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_anonymous',
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Custom callback function.
 */ 
function page_prog_custom() {
  $content['raw_markup'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<p>Hello world</p>',
  );

  return $content;
}
```

This is what the User module does for *user/login* route, which is only accessible to anonymous users. (See [`user_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_menu/7.x).)

```
  $items['user/login'] = array(
    'title' => 'Log in',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_anonymous',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
```

The alternative (which I don't suggest, but I show here just to point out what is wrong in the code you tried to use) would implementing a custom permission that is then used for that page, and assigned only to the anonymous users (i.e. every other role, including the *authenticated user*, will not have the custom permission used from that page).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function page_prog_menu() {
  $items['page_prog/custom'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Custom page',
    'page callback' => 'page_prog_custom',
    'access arguments' => 'access page_prog content',
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Custom callback function.
 */ 
function page_prog_custom() {
  $content['raw_markup'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<p>Hello world</p>',
  );

  return $content;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function page_prog_permission() {
  return array(
    'access page_prog content' => array(
    'title' => t('Access content to the custom pages'),
  ));
}
```

The code you shown doesn't work because the access arguments were not set to an array containing the custom permission defined from the module. Then, it would not work if the custom permission is not assigned to anonymous users, and just to them.